# Generate a thumbnail from a Channel File field with CE Image

Tags: image, ce-image, thumbnails, channel-files

I'm using a Channel Files field where the client can upload documents or images. If an image has been uploaded, I then want to be able to create a cached thumbnail in the template.

I'm trying to use CE Image but just can't get it to generate anything. Has anyone else tried doing this with Channel Files and CE Image?

My code is below;

```
{cf_channel_file limit="1"}

    {if file:extension == 'jpg' OR file:extension == 'jpeg' OR file:extension == 'png'}

        {exp:ce_img:pair src="{file:url}" crop="yes" width="238" height="244"}
            <img src="{made}" width="{width}" height="{height}" />
        {/exp:ce_img:pair}

    {/if}

{/cf_channel_file}
```

Comment: try to remove {if} condition , and tell me.

Comment: Hey Ahmad, no dice i'm afraid. :(

Comment: ok my fault keep {if} removed and add `parse="inward"` to `{cf_channel_file limit="1" parse="inward"}` if this don't work use `{exp:channel_files:files}` with `parse="inward"` intead. try it and tell me

Comment: Thanks man, still no lcuk. I even tried adding parse to the channel entries tag.

Comment: as I think `parse="inward"` not wrok on channel entries tag , it works on addons only, any way can you enable Template Debugging ans post how {exp:ce_img:pair src="{file:url}" crop="yes" width="238" height="244"} tag look like

Comment: Hey Ahmad. I turned on template debugging and it looks like it was a combination of caching issue and permissions to the cached folder. All fixed now. Thank you for your help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: dose `parse="inward"` do the trick